# strcmp() not returning what it should return

Tags: c, string, string-comparison, strcmp

Basically I want to create a program that would have potential questions that might be in my upcoming exam in Digital Systems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char input1[600];
    printf("What is the set of available registers?");
    scanf("%s", &input1);

    if(strcmp(input1, "registers, memory, hard disc") == 0){
        printf("Good job! You got it right");
    }
    else {
        printf("Wrong answer!");
    }
```

So whenever I type "registers, memory, hard disc" when I'm asked it returns 1 instead of 0. I cannot see the problem. I am kind of new to C so sorry if it is a silly question.

Comment: In a situation like this, you should print the string that you have read to see what it contains. That's basic debugging.

Comment: `scanf` famously (yes; it is by design) separates input on spaces.

Comment: "Standard library function X does not behave according to its documentation" is almost always a misdiagnosis.  It is far more likely that the inputs are not what you think they are (as here), or even that you've misunderstood the docs.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Undefined behaviour is invoked, as `%s` expects a `char*`, but the code shown passes a `char**`. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said in the comments, `scanf()` with `"%s"` stops conversion at the first whitespace character. To read a whole line of text, use `fgets()`:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// ...

char foo[100];
if(!fgets(foo, sizeof(foo), stdin))  // don't use sizeof on pointers
    ; // handle error                // for that purpose!

size_t length = strlen(foo);
if(length && foo[length - 1] == '\n')  // fgets also reads the newline character 
   foo[--length] = '\0';               // at the end of the line, this removes it.
```

Comment: Good use of `fgets()` and good test to prevent  hacker exploit of entering a null character as the first character.

Comment: Nice one. `fgets` is of course preferable, but I added an answer on how to do with `scanf`

Answer (score 1):

Swordfish has already given a good answer, and `fgets` is preferable to `scanf`. However, I want to show how you would use `scanf` in this case:

```
if(scanf("%599[^\n]", input1) != 1) {
    // Handle error
}
```

So what is different?

1. `scanf` returns the number of successfully assignments, so if this returns 1, then `input1` has been assigned. If not, an error has occured.
2. Changed `s` to `[^\n]` to read until newline
3. Inserted `599` (one less than 600) so ensure that we don't write outside the array.
4. Removed `&` from `input1`. In this case, it would probably work anyway, but it is undefined behavior, which should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score -2):

Try change your scanf line from:

```
scanf("%s", &input1);
```

to:

`scanf("%[^\n]", input1);`

It worked out for me.